# Data Transfer Challenge: Maintaining Data Type Consistency Between Databases in Spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm facing a challenge while transferring data from one database to another. When I read tables from the source using Spark, I've noticed that the data types are changing. For instance, VARCHAR2(900) / VARCHAR2(4000) is being converted to str. This conversion creates issues when I attempt to insert the data into the second database. I've tried various methods to address this problem, but haven't achieved satisfactory results.

My goal is to have the tables created automatically in such a way that both tables in the two databases have exactly the same data types. Any insights or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

result type in data :

[image]

result type  to insert data :

[image]

1-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  # Create a Spark session spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()  # Assuming you have a DataFrame df df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "text1"), (2, "text2")], ["id", "column1"])  # Specify Oracle connection properties oracle_properties = {     "user": "user",     "password": "password",     "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",     "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:port/t", }  # Specify the Oracle table name oracle_table_name = "your_table_name"  # Specify the data type for the column (use STRING or VARCHAR) column_data_type = "STRING"  # Save the DataFrame to Oracle df.write \     .format("jdbc") \     .option("url", oracle_properties["url"]) \     .option("dbtable", oracle_table_name) \     .option("user", oracle_properties["user"]) \     .option("password", oracle_properties["password"]) \     .option("driver", oracle_properties["driver"]) \     .option("createTableColumnTypes", f"column1 {column_data_type}(600)") \     .mode("overwrite") \     .save()
```

2-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  # Create a Spark session spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()  # Assuming you have a DataFrame df df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "text1"), (2, "text2")], ["id", "column1"])  # Specify Oracle connection properties oracle_properties = {     "user": "user",     "password": "password",     "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",     "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:port/t", }  # Specify the Oracle table name oracle_table_name = "VARCHAR2_600"  # Specify the data type for the column column_data_type = "VARCHAR2(600)"  # Create the table in Oracle with the specified data type df.write \     .format("jdbc") \     .option("url", oracle_properties["url"]) \     .option("dbtable", oracle_table_name) \     .option("user", oracle_properties["user"]) \     .option("password", oracle_properties["password"]) \     .option("driver", oracle_properties["driver"]) \     .option("createTableColumnTypes", f"column1 {column_data_type}") \     .mode("overwrite") \     .save()
```

3-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:port/O"
user = "user"
password = "password"
table = "table"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("YourAppName").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('driver', driver).option('url', url).option('user', user).option('dbtable', table).option('password', password).load()

oracle_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip1:port2/O2"
oracle_properties = {
    "user": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
}

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateTableInOracleExample").getOrCreate()
table_name = "tspcbcif_test_sample_new"

df.write.jdbc(url=oracle_url, table=table_name, mode="overwrite", properties=oracle_properties)

read_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=oracle_url, table=table_name, properties=oracle_properties)
```

Comment: I have added your code in question .. Please delete your answer in answer section as it might confuse others.

Answer (score 1):

First Method:

```
.option("SetBigStringTryClob", "true")
```

In this method, you allow Oracle to insert large string values directly into the database.

Second Method:

```
df_converted = df.withColumn("column1", col("column1").cast("string").substr(1, 4000))
```

In this method, you need access to the database information to correctly insert these values into the database.

These methods provide two different approaches for handling large string values when working with Oracle databases. The first method involves a specific JDBC option that allows Oracle to handle large strings, while the second method involves manipulating the DataFrame in Spark to handle string length constraints before inserting into the database.